# ElasticSearch.Net does not recognize the timestamp returned by ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch.net

I'm trying to get a set of data from the kibana_sample_data_flights index which contains timestamp. When running the query, ElasticSearch correctly recognize it and returns the results but it crashes with

> invalid datetime format. value:2019-06-03T

on

> Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.Formatters.ISO8601DateTimeFormatter.Deserialize(JsonReader& reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver)

The first time, I thought it was my object that was wrongly indexed and simply excluded the result but I got the same error on another entry. Searching with Kibana, it works and the timestamp is *Jun 2, 2019 @ 20:00:00.000* which makes sense since I'm in UTC-5 zone.

How can I have NEST / ElasticSearch.net recognize the date correctly?

*--Edit 1: Elastic version and sample code as requested.*

I'm using NEST and ElasticSearch.Net v7.0.0. ElasticSearch version request returns

```
{
  "name" : "M79539",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "CxG9dTeSTsudlhJBGiVmJQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.1.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "606a173",
    "build_date" : "2019-05-16T00:43:15.323135Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

In case it could help, here is the program

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Kibana: http://m79539:5601/app/kibana#/home?_g=()
            // NEST
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://m79539:9200/"))
                .DefaultIndex("kibana_sample_data_flights")
                .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);

            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            var scrollTimeout = "5m";
            var scrollSize = 1000;
            var initialResponse = client.Search<FlightDetail>(s => s
                        .From(0).Take(scrollSize)
                        .Query(q => +q
                             .DateRange(r => r
                                    .Field(f => f.Timestamp)
                                    .GreaterThan(DateMath.Anchored(new DateTime(2019,06,01)))
                                    .LessThan(DateMath.Now)) && +!q
                              .Term(p => p.FlightNum, "59H86EL")
                          )
                        .Scroll(scrollTimeout)
                        //scroll is optimized for this sort and we will sort in our own code
                        .Sort(ss => ss.Ascending(SortSpecialField.DocumentIndexOrder))
                      );

            var results = new List<FlightDetail>();

            if (!initialResponse.IsValid || string.IsNullOrEmpty(initialResponse.ScrollId))
                throw new Exception(initialResponse.ServerError.Error.Reason);

            if (initialResponse.Documents.Any())
                results.AddRange(initialResponse.Documents);

            string scrollid = initialResponse.ScrollId;
            bool isScrollSetHasData = true;
            while (isScrollSetHasData)
            {
                ISearchResponse<FlightDetail> loopingResponse = client.Scroll<FlightDetail>(scrollTimeout, scrollid);
                if (loopingResponse.IsValid)
                {
                    results.AddRange(loopingResponse.Documents);
                    scrollid = loopingResponse.ScrollId;
                }
                isScrollSetHasData = loopingResponse.Documents.Any();
            }

            client.ClearScroll(new ClearScrollRequest(scrollid));


            foreach (var result in results){
                Console.WriteLine($"{result.Timestamp} | {result.FlightNum} | {result.FlightDelayMin}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class FlightDetail
    {
        public string FlightNum { get; set; }
        public int FlightDelayMin { get; set; }
        public object Source { get; set; }

        [Nest.Text(Name = "timestamp")]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }
```

The problematic result (on my installation) is 548

```
{
    "_scroll_id": "DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAANizsWaTdsY3ViS2hUR2FyRHZESmdKeVRWZw==",
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "terminated_early": true,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 9227,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "kibana_sample_data_flights",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1Lr3DmsBoDCXrrhScXCk",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
                "FlightNum": "86C3GQY",
                "DestCountry": "MX",
                "OriginWeather": "Sunny",
                "OriginCityName": "Rome",
                "AvgTicketPrice": 395.9230418749486,
                "DistanceMiles": 6362.054220749258,
                "FlightDelay": false,
                "DestWeather": "Damaging Wind",
                "Dest": "Licenciado Benito Juarez International Airport",
                "FlightDelayType": "No Delay",
                "OriginCountry": "IT",
                "dayOfWeek": 0,
                "DistanceKilometers": 10238.733787837495,
                "timestamp": "2019-06-03T",
                "DestLocation": {
                    "lat": "19.4363",
                    "lon": "-99.072098"
                },
                "DestAirportID": "AICM",
                "Carrier": "JetBeats",
                "Cancelled": false,
                "FlightTimeMin": 602.2784581080879,
                "Origin": "Leonardo da Vinci - Fiumicino Airport",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "lat": "41.8002778",
                    "lon": "12.2388889"
                },
                "DestRegion": "MX-DIF",
                "OriginAirportID": "FCO",
                "OriginRegion": "SE-BD",
                "DestCityName": "Mexico City",
                "FlightTimeHour": 10.037974301801464,
                "FlightDelayMin": 0
            },
            "sort": [4379]
        }]
    }
}
```

*--- Edit 2 :* Simpler code sample based on @Rob proposition. Ends with the same problem. I added the try/catch to be able to break on errors and then look at what went through in Fiddler.

```
        private static void SimpleSample()
        {
            var client = new ElasticClient(new Uri("http://m79539:9200"));

            for (var i = 0; ; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var results = client.Search<SampleData>(s => s
                        .Index("kibana_sample_data_flights")
                        .From(i * 10)
                        .Query(q => q.MatchAll()));

                    foreach (var document in results.Documents)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(document.Timestamp.ToString("f") + "|" + document.FlightNum);
                    }
                }
                catch (Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private class SampleData
        {
            public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
            [Nest.Text(Name = "FlightNum")]
            public string FlightNum { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you targeting? Could you also please provide a minimal but complete, example that reproduces what you're seeing? It'll help in providing context to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample app which can retrieve timestamp data from [kibana_sample_data_flights](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-sample-data.html) index.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new ElasticClient(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

        var results = client.Search<SampleData>(s => s
            .Index("kibana_sample_data_flights").Query(q => q.MatchAll()));

        foreach (var document in results.Documents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(document.Timestamp.ToString("f"));
        }
    }
}

internal class SampleData
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

produces the following output:

```
Monday, 17 June 2019 00:00
Monday, 17 June 2019 18:27
Monday, 17 June 2019 17:11
Monday, 17 June 2019 10:33
Monday, 17 June 2019 05:13
Monday, 17 June 2019 01:43
Monday, 17 June 2019 13:49
Monday, 17 June 2019 04:54
Monday, 17 June 2019 12:09
Monday, 17 June 2019 12:09
```

In the example, NEST was able to correctly map SampleData property `Timestamp` to index's field `timestamp`  because of the [default field name convention being used](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html#camel-casing).

**UPDATE**

Indeed there was an issue with parsing incorrect date value for document with id `1Lr3DmsBoDCXrrhScXCk` z and value "timestamp": "2019-06-03T",`.

We can handle the error with customizing serialization when defining `ConnectionSettings` object and keep going when we encounter an error:

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var connectionSettings =
    new ConnectionSettings(pool,
        sourceSerializer: (builtin, settings) => new JsonNetSerializer(
            builtin, settings,
            () => new JsonSerializerSettings {Error = HandlerError}
        ));
var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

private static void HandlerError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
{
    //handle error the way you like
    e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
}
```

Now we get this output:

```
..
Wednesday, 19 June 2019 21:39

Thursday, 20 June 2019 04:47
Thursday, 20 June 2019 21:51
Thursday, 20 June 2019 02:27
..
```

You can read more about configuring serialization process in NEST [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think it is simply because you didn't go far enough in the results...
I added the following to your code and it crashes at i == 33.    

for (var i = 0; ; i++)
{
 [...]
 .From(i*10)
 [...]
}

Comment: Could you include in your question full NEST query you have tried with my example?

Comment: It is exactly the same except I added a loop around the client.search line.

Comment: Show it please :)

Comment: I modified the post with edit 2. As you will see, for debugging purpose, I also added a try/catch

Comment: @bkqc thanks for posting more details, check my update.

Comment: Though it is very interesting and has some potential (I will clearly dig into this), it doesn't fix the problem since the values without T00:00:00 are simply missing though they should be correct. Why would Kibana be able to read these values correctly but not our .NET code?

Comment: Also, why would Elastic send a buggy date without the time?

Comment: It happens. Will report.